# SQLite: Current date plus one day in where clause

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I need to get 3 queries on an 'appointment' table.

1. where appointment.start_date is today,
2. where appointment.start_date = today+1 day, and
3. where appointment.start_date is > today+1 day.

I've got 1. down fine.

```
var resultSet = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date() = date(start_date)');
```

For 2., I've tried this:

```
var resultSet = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date("now", "+1day") = date(start_date, "+1day")');
```

I got date('now', '+1day') from this link [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) but it returns the same results as the first query.

Can someone help with these queries?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using exactly what's posted, I'd say you have a spacing problem

SQLite uses '+1 day' and you have posted '+1day'

Barring any explicit error messages, with the space it *should* work

Comment: Sorry totally my own idiosity my query was wrong: `WHERE date("now", "+1day") = date(start_date, "+1day")` should have read `WHERE date("now", "+1day") = date(start_date)` I had an extra +1 day. Doh! Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for SQLite, but try next code:

```
var now = new Date();
var nowStr = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(now.getMonth()+1)+"-"+now.getDate();
var nowPlus1 = new Date(Number(now)+24*60*60*1000);
var nowPlus1Str = nowPlus1.getFullYear()+"-"+(nowPlus1.getMonth()+1)+"-"+nowPlus1.getDate();

var resultSet = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_date = '" + nowStr + "'");

var resultSet = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_date = '" + nowPlus1Str + "'");

var resultSet = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_date > '" + nowPlus1Str + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry totally my own idiosity my query was wrong: WHERE date("now", "+1day") = date(start_date, "+1day") should have read WHERE date("now", "+1day") = date(start_date) I had an extra +1 day. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Try with "plus one day" instead of "+1 day". Its not documented, but worked for me in another code.

```
var resultSet = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date("now plus one day") = date(start_date plus one day")');
```